# SSRS Tablix space adjustment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the following report designed in my Report Designer:
[image]

The header is a text box followed by 2 tablix controls. But when I preview the report, the text box, the first tablix and the second tablix all appear in separate pages. I want them to appear in the same page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few properties to check that could be causing this. But this is not the default behavior so something must have been inadvertently changed.

1. Check the `PageBreak` properties for each table (textboxes don't have this). The `BreakLocation` should be set to "None".
2. In the Report properties, check the `PageSize` and `InteractiveSize`. These are normally "8.5in, 11in" or the equivalent for your region.

If all else fails you may need to start with a fresh report.